# Kubernetes Pod on AWS - Can't get the Pod outside of the AWS

Tags: docker, aws, kubernetes

I'm trying to pull docker image from DockerHub.
When I create a Pod with the deployment code below
I get Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox

This is the deployment.yaml file:

```
    apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: exchange-app 
spec:
  containers:
    - name: exchange-application 
      image: yakir1992/exchange-app
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      command: [ "echo", "SUCCESS" ]
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: myregistrykey
  tolerations:
    - key: "node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane"
      operator: "Exists"
```

I tried to create a new subnet.env file with the following:

```
FLANNEL_NETWORK=10.240.0.0/16
FLANNEL_SUBNET=10.240.0.1/24
FLANNEL_MTU=1450
FLANNEL_IPMASQ=true
```

Still can't get the Pod outside.

I want to pull a docker image from dockerhub to my K8s Pod and open the service to the outside world.

Please help, thanks in advance!